# Angular directives way of defining

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

This example is from [Angular docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive). Could someone explain to me what exactly the following means?

```
<span my-dir="exp"></span>
```

I am talking about `exp`. **Why do we need that? What does it represent?**

Comment: Share the Angular docs link please.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Answer (score 1):

`expr` stands for `expression`, which in this case will be interpreted and evaluated by angularjs so that it can act like javascript from the directive declaration side.

This allow you to use it as an input param (aka `args`, aka `input`, etc) within your directive, it could be a function, an object a number, a string, a scope variable, etc. And from your directive side you are able to use this value for your directive purposes.

For example:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .directive('helloWorld', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {
        name: '@helloWorld'
      },
      template: 'Hello {{ name }}'
    };
  });
```

```html
<div ng-app="app">
  <span hello-world="World"></span>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0/angular.js"></script>
```

Comment: It(expression) can be useful when we want to give some conditional data to directive.